# Ruby: How to write `String#scrub` and `Object#presence`?

Tags: ruby, utf-8

I want to use `String#scrub` and `Object#presence` simply. Basically, I have the following code:

```
some_name = params[:name].presence || 'nobody'
```

This means if `params[:name]` exists then `some_name = params[:name]`, else `some_name = 'nobody'`.

If I try to use that method, I get an `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error:

```
s = "\x80\x80\x80"
s.present? #=> invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

To solve that issue, I tried using `String#scrub` ([Feature #6752](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/6752) on bugs.ruby-lang.org, available in Ruby 2.1 or using string-scrub gem)

```
assert_equal("\uFFFD\uFFFD\uFFFD", u("\x80\x80\x80").scrub)
```

In the end, I want to write:

```
some_name = params[:name].scrub.presence || 'nobody'
```

This brings `nil.scrub #=> undefined method 'scrub' for nil:NilClass`

Finally I wrote:

```
some_name = 'nobody' unless params[:name].is_a?(String)
some_name = params[:name].scrub.presence || 'nobody'
```

I'm confused and I want to more simple code!

Edited: There is no method like `NilClass#scrub`, `Fixnum#scrub`, `Array#scrub`, but only `String#scrub`.

Comment: What's wrong with `params[:name] || 'nobody'`?

Comment: check this: "" || "nobody"

Comment: params[:name].respond_to?(:scrub) ? params[:name] : 'nobody'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@bjhaid 's comment, `params[:name].respond_to?(:scrub) ? params[:name] : 'nobody'` gave me idea:

```
name = params[:name].respond_to?(:scrub) ? params[:name].scrub : params[:name]
@name = name.presence || 'nobody'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ["andand" gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/):

```
params[:name].andand.scrub.presence
```

Or use `try`:

```
params[:name].try(:scrub).presence
```

Answer (score 3):

```
nil.try(:some_method)
=>
nil
```

so you can use "try" for this situation:

```
some_name = params[:name].try(:scrub).presence || 'nobody'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

I create `awesome_scrub` gem, https://github.com/sanemat/awesome_scrub

This achieves,

before:

```
name = params[:name].respond_to?(:scrub) ? params[:name].scrub : params[:name]
@name = name.presence || 'nobody'
```

after:

```
@name = awesome_scrub(params[:name]).presence || 'nobody'
```